# BEP20 Contract need help ASAP please

Tags: ether, gas, gas-limit, bsc, binance

Getting errors about gas limits on a already successfully deployed contract and now transactions on Pancake swap aren’t going through with error “Pancake: K” or this message
“we are trying to fix a bug on the chain
[00:21]
this
code: -32603
data:
code: -32000
message: "gas required exceeds allowance (41335035) or always failing transaction"
proto: Object
message: "Internal JSON-RPC error."
proto: Object
and from user side“
This is the source code

https://github.com/papelprotocol/Papel.sol/blob/main/Papel.sol

We need help ASAP there’s a lot of holders contract has already been audited what am I missing?!

Comment: Without looking at code, my guess is that the token has some internal fee and swaps fail due to that. At least Uniswap has special functions to call for such token swaps, dunno if Pancake supports those

Comment: Just realized I submitted  the wrong link here you go https://github.com/papelprotocol/Papel.sol/blob/main/Papel.sol

Comment: As mentioned by Lauri, it is likely because your token does not transfer the amount equal the parameter set by a user (or a pancake pair) when calling the transfer function. Can you edit your question to describe what your tokens does when a transfer is made? Such as fees, burns, etc. This is likely the problem.